# How to fix smartfilterbar to to top while scrolling

Tags: sapui5

Is it possible to fix a smartfilterbar to the top while scolling similar to the sticky property for the table tag, where the control remains fixed at the top of the page during vertical scrolling?

My Coding:

```
<IconTabFilter id="ITBId" text="{i18n>Name}">
        <smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar id="smartFilterBar" entitySet="SomeText" liveMode="true" useToolbar="true" showFilterConfiguration="true" considerSelectionVariants="true" header="{i18n>Text}">
                <smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>
                        <smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration key="SomeKey" index="1" visibleInAdvancedArea="true" label="SomeLabel">
                        ...
                        </smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration>
                </smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>
        </smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar>
        ...
</IconTabFilter>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to make header sticky.

In XML, remove sticky property:

```
<m:Table id="table" mode="MultiSelect">
```

In your controller file:

```
onAfterRendering: function() {
    // Stick the toolbar and header of the smart table to top. 
    var oSmartTable = this.byId("__smartTableWorklist");
    oSmartTable.onAfterRendering = function() {
        var oToolbar = this.byId("stickyToolbar"),
            oParent = oToolbar.$().parent();
        if (oParent) {
            oParent.addClass("cimtStickyToolbar");
        }
    }.bind(this);
        // This is new code to make the table's header also sticky
    var oTable = this.byId("table");
    oTable.onAfterRendering = function() {
        oTable.addStyleClass("cimtStickyTableMSW");
        var oToolbar = this.byId("stickyToolbar"),
        iTop = oToolbar.$().outerHeight();
        if ($("head").find("style#cimtStickyTableMSW").length !== 0) {
            $("head").find("style#cimtStickyTableMSW").remove();
        }
        var style = $("<style id='cimtStickyTableMSW'></style>");
        $(style).html(" .cimtStickyTableMSW > table > thead > tr," +
            ".cimtStickyTableMSW > table > thead > tr > th {" +
            "   position: sticky;" +
            "   position: -webkit-sticky;" +
            "   top: " + iTop + "px;" +
            "   z-index: 100;" +
            "}");
        $("head").prepend(style); //eslint-disable-line
    }.bind(this);
}, // end of afterRendering handler of the view.
```

[Reference Link](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/05/03/fixed-header-for-ui5-smart-table/)

Comment: Thanks for the responds.I do not have sticky property in my coding. What do you mean with 'You need to make header sticky'? Or do you suggest to rebuild my Coding? Is it possible to use the smartFilterBar tag like in my question?

Comment: You can use smarttable. It does support smartfilterbar (https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable)